# Safari Drag&Drop ghost element is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, drag-and-drop

I have a fixed element where I have a drag/drop elements. I move this fixed element with translateX, and when this element is moved and I use drag&drop, the ghost element is no longer visible.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

What happens is, we are moving element header with translateX as we cannot use left property, because their stupid ass doesn't have hardware acceleration on left property. Now because we use translateX browser gets confused when using drag&drop and it doesn't know where to position the ghost element.

Now what I did is. When we are opening and closing the navigator (translateX 544|0), we are using translateX and when UI is static (no open|close navigator) we use left property.